# What is the input timezone for javascript `new Date` function?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to figure out what timezone does the `new Date` function take as input referencing this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for both Chrome and Firefox

From the documentation for parameter

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method

It didn't really specify what timezone it takes.

For example if I have

```
new Date("2016-08-14 23:59:59")
```

What timezone does the browser interpret for my input, I know its final output is local timezone, but is the input interpret as local timezone as well?

Comment: The spec says: *"The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format ([20.3.1.16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to **any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats**."*

Comment: @FelixKling Where did you find that? I search `The String may` but couldn't find the quote in documentation I referenced.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.parse

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm it seems like the documentation you provided is for `es6` and not the currently used `es5` javascript

Comment: ES6 is the current standard... of course not all features are supported by every browser, but that doesn't make it any less current.

Comment: This changed from ES5 to ES6, different browsers in different versions do it differently. You should not rely on anything. **Always explicitly specify the timezone**, or use your own custom parsing algorithm/library.

Comment: @testing—the correct names for the standard are "ECMA-262 6th Edition" or "ECMAScript 2015". There is an intention for annual releases, at least for ECMAScript 2016 and ECMAScript 2017. The language will change hugely by then and include thread management (that's the plan at least).